# Sample method returns empty featureCollection (GEE)

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, clustering, sentinel-2

I have some troubles with the `sample` method from **Google Earth Engine**. On some images, it returns an **empty** feature collection (0 element).

Why this is happening and how do I deal with that ?

It's problematic to train a model on an empty dataset...

Here one illustration:

```js
// Example on two images : one working, not the other
var image_ok = ee.Image("COPERNICUS/S2/20150627T102531_20160606T223605_T31RFN");
var image_empty = ee.Image("COPERNICUS/S2/20151228T002843_20151228T085259_T54HYD");
var VisImg = {"opacity":1,"bands":["B4","B3","B2"],"min":293.6805388296989,"max":2220.5270083401124,"gamma":1};

// Sampling
var training_ok = image_ok.sample({numPixels:1000});
var training_empty = image_empty.sample({numPixels:1000});

// Display
print("Ok: ", training_ok);
print("Empty: ", training_empty);

Map.addLayer(image_empty, VisImg, "Image empty");
Map.addLayer(image_ok, VisImg, "Image ok");
Map.centerObject(image_empty);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "empty" image contains QA bands that are completely masked out. You can avoid the empty sample by first selecting the bands that have valid data. For example:

```
var training_empty = image_empty
  .select([
    'B1',
    'B2',
    'B3',
    'B4',
    'B5',
    'B6',
    'B7',
    'B8',
    'B8A',
    'B9',
    'B10',
    'B11',
    'B12',
    // 'QA10',
    // 'QA20',
    // 'QA60',
  ])
  .sample({numPixels:1000});
```